# Redux action is not returning payload data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, visual-web-developer

I am facing a problem when returning data from my action to redux.

my action is as follows:

```
export const getUserProfile = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/getuserprofile",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    var res, user;
    const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated") === "true";
    var decodedToken = null;
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      decodedToken = jwt_decode(access_token);
      user = decodedToken.sub;
    }
    try {
      res = await axios
        .get(`${host}/manageAdmins/getUserProfile/${user}`)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data, { source: "API" });
        }
   }
);
```

In my reducer the code is as follows:

```
   builder.addCase(getUserProfile.pending, (state, action) => {
           console.log("pending");
    });
   builder.addCase(getUserProfile.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
           console.log("my payload: ");
           console.log(action.payload);
           state.userProfile = action.payload;
   });
   builder.addCase(getUserProfile.rejected, (state, action) => {
           console.log("rejected");
   });
```

When I console the payload, it says `undefined`. But when I console my data in the action part, it has a value that I want. the problem is that it does not respond payload to the reducer.

is there another way to return data when state is fulfilled? I've tried **fulfillWithValue(value, meta)** that I've seen from the documentation. but not working. some one please help me in doing. this. I appreciate!`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return res` - currently you are receiving that data, but not doing anything with it.